# Pass a file path as a URL parameter in Django

Tags: django, filepath, url-parameters

I'm using Django to create a webapp. When a user press on a certain button, it needs to pass a file path as parameter and a string parameter to one of my views. I can't simply use the  parameter in the URL since the path contains several '/'. The way I have it setup right now is as follows:

**parameters.py**

```
class FilePathConverter:
regex = '^[/]'

def to_python(self, value):
    value=str(value)
    return value.replace("?", "/")

def to_url(self, value):
    value=str(value)
    return value.replace("/", "?")
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views import generic
from django.urls import path, register_converter
from . import converters, views

register_converter(converters.FilePathConverter, 'filepath')

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.index, name='webpanel-index'),
   path('controlserver/<filepath:server_path>/<str:control>', views.index, name='controlserver'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Server
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
import subprocess

def controlserver(request, server_path, control):
    if request.POST:
        subprocess.call(['bash', server_path, control])
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

However, with this method, I get this error:

```
Reverse for 'controlserver' with keyword arguments '{'server_path': 'rien/', 'control': 'start'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['controlserver/(?P<server_path>[^/]+)/(?P<control>[^/]+)$']
```

Comment: if you want to operate on paths you should get familiar with [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). It's a quick way to handle strings as Path objects and modify them using built-in methods. If you find this comment helpful don't forget to upvote it :) if you need more help just ask but firstly read the pathlib docs linked at the beginning

Comment: It looks like somewhere you are trying to reverse the `controlserver` url, but you are giving the value of `server_path` as `rien/`. This will never match a `str` value as it cannot contain a `/`

Comment: Try using the regular expression `[^/]+` for your converter. It's the same one django uses for `str` matching which should be the same as for your filepath if I've understood this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Slug to resolve this patterns by :

---

from django.utils.text import slugify

### path('controlserver/use slug .....', views.index, name='controlserver'),

but you need to put slug at views and templates So check this list of slug and pk  :

https://github.com/salah-cpu/migration/blob/master/PATH_slug_pk